# Understanding output extend of convolution kernels when blending

Tags: ios, metal, core-image, cifilter, cikernel

I want to process an image with a custom Metal-based convolution `CIKernel` and blend the result with other images into one composition.
But I’m observing strange clipping behavior during blending:

To illustrate the point, I created a simple composition like so:

```
let inputImage = CIImage(image: inputImage)
let filter = MyCustomFilter()
filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let filteredImage = filter.outputImage!.transformed(by: .init(translationX: 360, y: 300))
let background = CIImage(color: .white).cropped(to: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 1500, height: 1000)))

let composedImage = filteredImage.composited(over: background)
```

When `MyCustomFilter` does nothing (`return src.sample(src.coord())`), the result looks like this:
￼[image]

Now, if I perform an actual convolution (sample pixels around the middle pixel) in the filter like so

```
float4 testKernel(sampler src, destination dest) {
    return src.sample(src.transform(dest.coord() + float2(1,1)));
}
```

the result suddenly looks like this:
[image]￼

As you can see there’s suddenly some clamp-to-extend behavior added to the image when blending, even though its extend is still that of the `inputImage`.

I observed that Apple’s convolution filters return a larger output image that also contains a halo region depending on the filter parameters. So I played around a lot and found that if I tell the kernel to render into a larger extend and crop it afterwards, the blending again works as expected:

```
let output = self.kernel.apply(extent: inputExtent.insetBy(dx: -1, dy: -1),
                          roiCallback: roiCallback,
                            arguments: [inputImage])
return output.cropped(to: inputExtent)
```

It seems the blending filter somehow tries to sample the pixels just outside the image’s extent to determine how to fill the blank space. This *should* be transparent by default, but seemingly the convolution operation alone adds some clamp-to-edge behavior, even though I don’t change the result extent.

Does anyone know if this is a bug and/or what the best approach would be to combine custom convolution filters with compositions?